# Как создать элемент в таблице и внести в него данные python flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Есть `txt` файл в котором хранятся время начала работы таймера и время конца работы (промежуток 58 минут)

**file.txt:**

```
11:00:10 # начало первого захода
11:58:10 # конец первого захода
16:32:38 # начало второго захода
17:30:38 # конец второго захода
```

Эти данные читаются файлом `index.py` в котором подключается фреймворк `Flask` и `render_template` для того чтобы передать шаблону время начала и конца работы, которые хранятся в переменных `start_of_work/end_of_work`

**index.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

with open("filename.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    a = data[::2]   # нечетные строки
    b = data[1::2]  # четные строки
    start_of_work = ''.join(a)
    end_of_work = ''.join(b)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def begin():
    return render_template('entry.html', start=start_of_work, end=end_of_work)
```

Затем происходит добавление элементов в ячейки(но совсем не так как мне нужно) первый заход времени встраивается отлично, но второй встраивается туда же, куда и первый, то есть в ту же строку td

**entry.html:**

```
<table>
      <caption>Report</caption>
      <tr>
            <th>Beginning of work</th>
            <th>End of work</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
            <td>{{start}}</td>
            <td>{{end}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

И так вопрос: как сделать так чтобы следующее добавление(после первого) осуществлялось в следующий элемент tr td, чтобы был табличный вид, элемент под элементов. Как создать этот элемент и встроить туда эти данные(и так каждый раз при новом заходе)

И как осуществить обновление переменных, чтобы они не забирали с собой старые значения, то есть переменная `start_of_work` имела время только последнего захода, а не всего файла `txt`

Заранее благодарю за любые полезные ответы и советы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, дорога в ад программирования выложена глобальными переменными, поэтому все манипуляции с `file.txt` лучше вынести в отдельную функцию, которая будет возвращать массив с парами значений. Во-вторых, нет никакой необходимости для ваших задач пихать всё в одну строку, лучше наоборот всё сохранить как есть.

```
def get_start_end_times(filename):
   # Same as before
   return list(zip(a, b))
```

Дальше в самом шаблоне

```
<table>
{% for start,end in times %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ start }}</td>
    <td>{{ end }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

И всё, что нам остаётся - это просто подставить в шаблон список со списком значений.

```
@app.route('/')
def begin():
    return render_template(
        "entry.html",
        times=get_start_end_times("file.txt")
    )
```

Всё должно работать, но, возможно, потребует дополнительной отладки, но основная идея такая: хранить пару начало-конец захода в кортеже и хранить пары в списке, а потом использовать этот список пар в шаблонном цикле. Кроме того, я еще пользуюсь встроенной функцией `zip`, которая есть не во всех версиях python и я не могу сказать, в каких именно (в 3.5 уже точно есть).

Comment: спасибо вам) очень помогло!